# Не могу разобрать, как подсчитать количество столбцов, элементы которых расположены в порядке возрастания в двумерно массиве?

Tags: c++, массивы

Не могу разобрать, как подсчитать количество столбцов, элементы которых расположены в порядке возрастания в двумерно массиве ? c++

Я написал заполнение цикла, но не могу додуматься до остольного:

> как подсчитать количество столбцов, элементы которых расположены в порядке возрастания в двумерно массиве

Вот фрагмент кода программы которой не могу доделать:

```
    #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // Объявление переменных
    int numRows,numCols;
    
    
    // Запрос данных пользователя
    cout << "введите кол-во строк для матрицы: ";
    cin >> numRows ;
    cout << "введите кол-во столбоцов для матрицы: ";
    cin >> numCols;
    // cout << "Матрицы NxN равняется: " << numRows << "x" << numCols << endl;
    int a[numRows][numCols];
    
    // Заполнение массива 
    for (int i = 0; i < numRows;i++){
        cout << "Вводим " << i + 1 << " строку\n";
        for (int j = 0; j < numCols; j++){
            cout << "Введите целое число: ";
            cin >> a[i][j];
            }
    }
     // Вывод матрицы пользователя 
    cout << "Ваша матрица: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < numCols; j++) {
            cout << a[i][j] << ' ';
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    
    for(int j =1; j<numCols;j++){
        int count = 0;
        for(int i = 1; i<numRows - 1;i++){
            
            if( a[i + 1][j] > a[i][j] ){
                break;
            }
            if( i = numRows - 1 ){
                count = count + 1;
            }
            
        }
        cout << count;
    }
```

Comment: Во-первых, лучше привести весь код. Во-вторых, `if( i = numRows - 1 )` – скорее всего, ошибка – перепутали `==` и `=`. В третьих, что значит *заполнение цикла*? В-четвёртых, когда Вы начинаете циклы с 1, Вы пропускаете нулевой элемент массива (индексы в С/С++ начинаются с нуля).

Comment: Всё я выложил полностью код

Comment: А что насчёт остальных моих замечаний?

Comment: Заполнение цикла, т.е запрос данных пользователя и запись в массив, остальное делал все как но форумах говорили, я учусь просто)

Comment: Тогда уж заполнение массива, а не заполнение цикла. И условие всё-таки проверьте на предмет ошибки, описанной в моём первом комментарии.

Comment: серавно нечего не выходит

Comment: Так это понятно. Это только одна из ошибок. Сейчас напишу полный ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В последнем цикле есть пара логических ошибок. Рассмотрим Ваш код подробнее:

```cpp
for(int j =1; j<numCols;j++)
{
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i<numRows - 1; i++)
    {
        if( a[i + 1][j] > a[i][j] )
        {
            break;
        }
        if( i = numRows - 1 )
        {
            count = count + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Во-первых, опечатка, которую я указал в комментарии: `if( i = numRows - 1 )`. У вас здесь вместо знака равенства оператор присваивания. Вот что произойдёт при вычислении результата условия: переменной `i` будет присвоено значение `numRows - 1`, а потом, т.к. `if` работает только с данными логического типа, `i` будет преобразована к типу `bool` по правилу "Если `0`, то `false`, иначе – `true`". Таким образом, условие будет выполнено в каждом случае, когда `numRows - 1` не равно нулю.

Во-вторых, если поправить это условие, столкнёмся с другой, уже логической, ошибкой: тело цикла выполняется до тех пор, пока `i < numRows - 1`, следовательно, условие, заключённое в этом теле, `if( i == numRows - 1 )` никогда не будет выполнено, т.к. к моменту, когда оно будет достигнуто, цикл уже перестанет выполняться. Следовательно, скорее всего, нужно заменить `numRows - 1` на `numRows - 2`.

В-третьих, циклы почему-то начинаются от 1, хотя наименьший индекс массива в c++ – 0.

В-четвёртых, конструкция

```cpp
    if( a[i + 1][j] > a[i][j] )
    {
        break;
    }
```

вероятно, предназначена, чтобы, когда не выполняется условие "элементы идут по возрастанию", переходить к следующему столбцу. Но, если `a[i + 1][j] > a[i][j]`, то элементы как раз идут по возрастанию. Значит данное условие нужно заменить на обратное:

```cpp
    if( a[i + 1][j] <= a[i][j] )
    {
        break;
    }
```

Я намеренно не стану прилагать к ответу готовый код с полным решением, чтобы автор вопроса прочитал мои замечания и постарался сам разобраться в своих ошибках и исправить их, а не просто скопировал готовый код, не обратив внимания на всё, что я так старательно здесь расписывал. Замечаний, представленных выше, достаточно, чтобы исправить программу до рабочего состояния.

Comment: Спасибо большое !

Comment: @Matef, если мой ответ решил Вашу проблему, примите его и проголосуйте, чтобы другие люди также могли видеть, что он верный.

Comment: Хорошо, ещё раз спасибо